# started removing a physical volume from an LVM from webmin. how can I see the progress?

Tags: lvm, pvmove

so I recently added a 2TB physical volume (PV) to an LVM volume group (VG) with the sole purpose of removing another 2TB PV from the VG. Everything is carried out from webmin.

So once the extra PV was appended to the LVM , remove the excess PV by pressing "remove from VG". Then webmin asked

```
Are you sure you want to remove physical volume device /dev/sdc from its volume group? This will result in any data being shifted to other physical volumes within the group.
```

Once  I accepted the website didn't change (but the loading animation is ...loading all the time) . Now, I am stuck in this webmin page which has no progress bar and I don't know if I should navigate away or leave it as is.

`ps` shows that

```
root@samothraki:~# ps aux | grep -i pv
root      3436  0.0  0.3  79608 30524 ?        S    02:38   0:00 /usr/libexec/webmin-1.660/lvm/save_pv.cgi
root      3446  0.0  0.0  17748  1292 ?        S    02:38   0:00 sh -c yes | pvmove \/dev\/sdc 2>&1
root      3448  0.0  0.6  68012 52412 ?        S    02:38   0:08 pvmove /dev/sdc
```

something is going on but the command arguments do not make be feel at ease. According to `pvmove` documentation, I should be see a source and destination drive as arguments... no?

The big question is how can I verify that the operation is indeed progressing? `pvdisplay`, `pvscan`, and `vgdisplay` don't seem to notify accordingly....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lvs -a -o +devices
```

For instance you can see my move is 8.6% complete

```
  LV             VG            Attr   LSize Origin Snap%  Move     Log Copy%  Convert Devices                
  [pvmove0]      storage-group p-C-ao 3.64t               /dev/sdb       8.61         /dev/sdb(0),/dev/sda(0)
  storage-volume storage-group -wI-ao 3.64t                                           pvmove0(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ran `pvmove` yourself with the `-v` (verbose) flag then you would be able to see progress. But since you ran it in the background through a web app, you are stuck. You will just have to wait it out.

In the meantime, you might want to spend some time learning how the system really works, rather than relying on the crutch of webmin.

Comment: it always a matter of time available, and well surely `webmin` could provide a progress by running the `pvmove` with `-v` flag.